# How to get system information like cpu, memory, gpu usage?

Tags: c, linux

There is tools like `top`, `free`, `sensors`, however, these are intended to shell usage. Is there corresponding header files to obtain information such as cpu load, used/all (gpu) memory in a C program without parsing output or `/proc/*` files? I mean system (NOT my program) resource consumption. And being newbie in system programming, I am also curious about how to find (use) header files shipped with packages in my C programs?

Comment: C programs are compiled into binary, so there are no header or other source files "shipped with packages", unless you add them there manually.

Comment: All programs you mentioned are written in C and are open source, thus there are header files and other utilities to do the same as these utilities in C. `with packages in my C programs` C programs do not have "packages", what do you mean? You might want to read [free.c sources](https://github.com/shichao-an/procps-ng-3.3.10/blob/master/free.c) and [top.c sources](https://github.com/shichao-an/procps-ng-3.3.10/blob/master/top/top.c) and [sensors main.c](https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors/blob/master/prog/sensors/main.c)

Comment: Why do you *not* want to use the `/proc` file system ? That's what it's for.

Comment: Look into `libprocps` - it's the library used by `top`, etc. to read info from `/proc`. On Debian you'd install the `libprocps-dev` package to get the header files.

Comment: `without parsing output or /proc/* files` - the utilities you mentioned do exactly that, it's a standard way of communicating with kernel. For example free parses [/proc/meminfo](https://github.com/shichao-an/procps-ng-3.3.10/blob/master/proc/sysinfo.c#L54).

Comment: I meant when I installed `vte3` or `libvterm` package I was able to `include <vte/vte.h>` in my C program and use its API. For those who suggest to parse `/proc/*` files, I did not know that it is a common way. Then I should dig into it, thanks.

Comment: @KamilCuk, how do you find source code? I mean, I see no authors (sources) when I `man top`. I assume there is a lot of `top` forks on github, how can I be sure that I found the original one?

Comment: When you have [man top](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) usually near the end there is `This page is part of the procps-ng` or `Written by blabla` or `This utility is part of <package>` etc. Then you do [`procps-ng github` in google](https://www.google.com/search?q=procps-ng+github) and you get milion mirrors of procps-ng repo available on github. Then you [find](https://github.com/shichao-an/procps-ng-3.3.10/find/master) a file inside the github repo. Most of the time simple `program_name github` just works in google.

Comment: You may also take a look at [htop](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/tree/master/linux) to see how it extracts the information (sysctl + /proc parsing, etc).

Comment: in linux, open: `software updater`,  click the `settings` button, click the `ubuntu software` and/or `Other Software` tabs,  click the: `source code` item. Exit the program.  in a terminal window,  enter: `apt-get update`  This will download the source code for each of the utilities and the version of the linux OS on your computer

Comment: @user3629249, it is probably distribution specific commands, anyway thanks. I forgot I can simply use web interface or some flags for my package manager to obtain the source code.